# Adding custom page numbering in footer

Tags: css, r, knitr, pagedown

I am trying to create a resume using the pagedown package. I got everything up and running, however, I don't seem to figure out how to add a custom page numbering like (page X of N)

How would you do such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify running headers/footers using custom CSS styles. There exist three default CSS files within pagedown: `default.css`, `default-page.css` and `default-font.css`.
You find those files here https://github.com/rstudio/pagedown/blob/main/inst/resources/css/.

In order to create a custom running footer/header you have to do the following:

1. Copy the default content of `default-page.css`.
2. Edit the styles. If you want to have the page numbers on alternating sides, you have to add this:

```
@page :left {
    @bottom-left {
        content: 'Page ' counter(page) ' of ' counter(pages);
    }
}
@page :right {
    @bottom-right {
        content: 'Page ' counter(page) ' of ' counter(pages);
    }
}
```

You can find more info on "generated content" and counters in the documentation of [Paged.js](https://www.pagedjs.org/documentation/06-generated-content/).
There are also "special" pages like `@page :first` or `@page chapter:left` which declare the styles for exactly those pages: the first page, and the left pages inside chapters.

3. Save the file as `custom-page.css` in the same directory as your RMarkdown script.
4. Add the custom styles in the YAML header:

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "Martin Schmelzer"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pagedown::html_paged:
    css:
      - default-fonts
      - custom-page.css
      - default
---
```

**It is important to also add the other two default files here.**